# Переход c HTTP на HTTPS

Tags: javascript, html, http, https, http-status-code-301

Всем привет ! Не могу решить проблем с переносом с http на https.
У меня в .htaccess файле написано так:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/assets
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule page/assets/img/([^.]+\.(jpe?g|gif|bmp|png))$ /assets/img/$1 [R=301,L,NC]
RewriteRule page/assets/img/uploads/([^.]+\.(jpe?g|gif|bmp|png))$ /assets/img/uploads/$1 [R=301,L,NC]
RewriteRule admin/assets/img/([^.]+\.(jpe?g|gif|bmp|png))$ /assets/img/$1 
[R=301,L,NC]
RewriteRule admin/assets/img/uploads/([^.]+\.(jpe?g|gif|bmp|png))$ 
/assets/img/uploads/$1 [R=301,L,NC]
```

Когда добавляю к себе еще

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$ 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://site(.)by/$1 [R=301,L]
```

HTTPS появляется но сайт падает
Подскажите если сталкивались с такой проблемой.

Answer (score 1):

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =off

RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [QSA,L]

Попробуйте вот так.

Comment: Мне выдает, 404 страничку, что не найдено.

Answer (score 0):

Нужно переписать

RewriteCond %{HTTPS}=OFF
тогда оно будет перенаправлять ваш запрос
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [QSA,L]

Comment: Мне выдает, 404 страничку, что не найдено.